# Git (Diffusion / Phabricator) remote repo returns 403 after password reset

Tags: git, phabricator

I recently changed my vcs password on a Phabricator remote repository. All was well until I attempted to push to an old remote and was getting a 403 returned.

I kept trying different things on the Phabricator server and then reset my vcs password to the previous one. VOILA, it worked.

Is there a way in my .git/ directory or global settings for it to forget my previously provided credentials? Is there something from the Phabricator UI I need to do?

Comment: This sounds like a Git issue, not something with Phabricator -- we don't cache your credentials on the server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turned out to be an OSX Keychain issue. Cleared it out and was given a prompt on the next push.